# Can't view any calendar view

Tags: sharepoint, calendar

Has anyone seen it where a user cannot view any calendar views across site collections? He can see all the events in standard list view format, but any calendar-type view only shows the month and no events.

Could this be an IE issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one took a little bit of thought. The user could access calendar views on other machines, so I had the user repair his MS Office Profile and reboot. That did the trick, as he was then able to see any calendar view across any site collection.